# Distribution of the increments of a Poisson Process with random rate

Tags: probability, poisson-process

If the rate of a Poisson process follows Gamma distribution, it is known that the total number of arrivals follows a negative binomial distribution. How about the conditional distribution of the increments of the Poisson process, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(N(t+h)=m|N(t)=n)$

Comment: Hi @J. Lin, as a good practice on the website, what have you tried till now? What are your ideas regarding the same? Always try to post that along with your question. It's helpful for the contributors who are trying to help.

Comment: "It is known that the total number of arrivals follows a negative binomial distribution" - do you mean the total number of arrivals up to some time $t$?